# Interceptor get stuck on it's creation, in POST request

Tags: android, web-services, http-post, retrofit2, interceptor

I have a application that need to do a POST request for my server sending a list of item through JSON. But to perform this POST it needs a header configuration with a token auth. When I send the request from the app, on the logcat, it´s possible to see the interceptor instantiation get stuck.
Please, take a look on my code and the logcat debug:

```
public static Retrofit getServerClient(String token) {
    Log.d("DEBUG 1 -> ","getServerClient");
    OkHttpClient httpClient;
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
            .create();
    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(SERVER_BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));
    if (token!=null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(token)) {
        Log.d("DEBUG 2 -> ","getServerClient needs add header");
        httpClient = getHttpClientWithInterceptor(token);
        Log.d("DEBUG 8 -> ","getServerClient with headers");
    }else {
        httpClient = getOkHttpClient();
    }
    builder.client(httpClient);
    Log.d("DEBUG 9 -> ","Return server client");
    return builder.build();
}

private static OkHttpClient getHttpClientWithInterceptor(final String token) {
    Log.d("DEBUG 3 -> ","Instantiate interceptor");
    Interceptor interceptor = new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) {
            try {
                Log.d("DEBUG 4 -> ","Add headers START");
                final Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+token)
                        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .build();
                Log.d("DEBUG 5 -> ","Add headers END");
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("DEBUG 6 -> ","Failure on request build");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    };

    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    httpClient.addNetworkInterceptor(interceptor);
    Log.d("DEBUG 7 -> ","Return client with interceptor");
    return httpClient.build();
}
```

What is weird in the GET request it works as you can see:

```
    10-30 09:40:16.081 8379-8379/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience D/DEBUG 1 ->: getServerClient
    10-30 09:40:16.097 8379-8379/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience D/DEBUG 2 ->: getServerClient needs add header
    10-30 09:40:16.097 8379-8379/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience D/DEBUG 3 ->: Instantiate interceptor
    10-30 09:40:16.103 8379-8379/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience D/DEBUG 7 ->: Return client with interceptor
    10-30 09:40:16.104 8379-8379/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience D/DEBUG 8 ->: getServerClient with headers
    10-30 09:40:16.104 8379-8379/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience D/DEBUG 9 ->: Return server client
    10-30 09:40:16.193 8379-8425/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa39a67a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa39ef300)
    10-30 09:40:16.256 8379-8455/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience D/DEBUG 4 ->: Add headers START
    10-30 09:40:16.256 8379-8455/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience D/DEBUG 5 ->: Add headers END
```

But on the POST it drops on a loops as the follow log:

```
        10-30 09:45:56.882 12054-12054/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience D/DEBUG 1 ->: getServerClient
10-30 09:45:56.897 12054-12054/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience D/DEBUG 2 ->: getServerClient needs add header
10-30 09:45:56.897 12054-12054/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience D/DEBUG 3 ->: Instantiate interceptor
10-30 09:45:56.901 12054-12054/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience D/DEBUG 7 ->: Return client with interceptor
10-30 09:45:56.902 12054-12054/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience D/DEBUG 8 ->: getServerClient with headers
10-30 09:45:56.902 12054-12054/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience D/DEBUG 9 ->: Return server client
10-30 09:45:56.920 12054-12059/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=26KB
10-30 09:45:56.921 12054-12059/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience I/art: After code cache collection, code=29KB, data=26KB
10-30 09:45:56.921 12054-12059/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
10-30 09:45:56.994 12054-12061/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.348ms
10-30 09:45:57.005 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.870ms
10-30 09:45:57.412 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 47547(884KB) AllocSpace objects, 6(120KB) LOS objects, 3% free, 18MB/19MB, paused 5.274ms total 17.663ms
10-30 09:45:57.928 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.320ms
10-30 09:45:57.934 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 175307(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 22(576KB) LOS objects, 16% free, 15MB/18MB, paused 6.735ms total 28.375ms
10-30 09:45:58.380 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.855ms
10-30 09:45:58.388 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 149517(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 18(572KB) LOS objects, 18% free, 17MB/21MB, paused 9.750ms total 35.467ms
10-30 09:45:58.493 12054-12061/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.182ms
10-30 09:45:58.555 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.622ms
10-30 09:45:58.563 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 180086(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 17(548KB) LOS objects, 14% free, 18MB/21MB, paused 9.906ms total 36.522ms
10-30 09:45:58.569 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.073ms
10-30 09:45:58.718 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.127ms
10-30 09:45:58.726 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 151954(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 17(604KB) LOS objects, 17% free, 19MB/23MB, paused 9.878ms total 43.588ms
10-30 09:45:58.732 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.808ms
10-30 09:45:58.995 12054-12061/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.158ms
10-30 09:45:59.277 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.132ms
10-30 09:45:59.640 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.369ms
10-30 09:45:59.981 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 11.514ms
10-30 09:45:59.994 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 186259(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 13(572KB) LOS objects, 10% free, 24MB/27MB, paused 14.243ms total 54.366ms
10-30 09:46:00.003 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.053ms
10-30 09:46:00.190 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.135ms
10-30 09:46:00.397 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.317ms
10-30 09:46:00.508 12054-12061/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.196ms
10-30 09:46:00.576 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.746ms
10-30 09:46:00.763 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.054ms
10-30 09:46:00.936 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.152ms
10-30 09:46:01.014 12054-12061/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.358ms
10-30 09:46:01.207 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 173843(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 11(572KB) LOS objects, 10% free, 29MB/32MB, paused 3.833ms total 120.445ms
10-30 09:46:01.499 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 176026(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 13(676KB) LOS objects, 11% free, 29MB/33MB, paused 7.948ms total 158.936ms
10-30 09:46:01.513 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 14.086ms
10-30 09:46:01.768 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 183401(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 10(540KB) LOS objects, 8% free, 30MB/33MB, paused 6.976ms total 55.042ms
10-30 09:46:01.782 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 14.141ms
10-30 09:46:02.091 12054-12061/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 83.993ms
10-30 09:46:02.119 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 146812(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 10(556KB) LOS objects, 11% free, 31MB/35MB, paused 4.086ms total 148.374ms
10-30 09:46:02.132 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 12.503ms
10-30 09:46:02.355 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 10.725ms
10-30 09:46:02.538 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 13.960ms
10-30 09:46:02.551 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 179103(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 8(448KB) LOS objects, 5% free, 33MB/35MB, paused 16.906ms total 86.519ms
10-30 09:46:02.561 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.621ms
10-30 09:46:02.713 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 13.718ms
10-30 09:46:02.730 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 176741(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 13(744KB) LOS objects, 10% free, 33MB/37MB, paused 17.026ms total 105.761ms
10-30 09:46:02.740 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.648ms
10-30 09:46:02.919 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 11.148ms
10-30 09:46:03.093 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 15.640ms
10-30 09:46:03.278 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.964ms
10-30 09:46:03.466 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 11.234ms
10-30 09:46:03.523 12054-12061/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.985ms
10-30 09:46:03.622 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 11.846ms
10-30 09:46:03.749 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 15.134ms
10-30 09:46:03.911 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.538ms
10-30 09:46:04.108 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 10.659ms
10-30 09:46:04.264 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 12.444ms
10-30 09:46:04.429 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 16.430ms
10-30 09:46:04.446 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 177011(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 13(860KB) LOS objects, 8% free, 40MB/44MB, paused 20.255ms total 121.688ms
10-30 09:46:04.461 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 15.013ms
10-30 09:46:04.530 12054-12061/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.298ms
10-30 09:46:04.670 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 11.041ms
10-30 09:46:04.839 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 12.578ms
10-30 09:46:05.030 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.919ms
10-30 09:46:05.242 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 13.381ms
10-30 09:46:05.400 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 14.841ms
10-30 09:46:05.537 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 14.684ms
10-30 09:46:05.735 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 15.828ms
10-30 09:46:05.755 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 191824(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 12(860KB) LOS objects, 8% free, 45MB/49MB, paused 19.760ms total 154.848ms
10-30 09:46:05.770 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 15.253ms
10-30 09:46:05.953 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 14.552ms
10-30 09:46:06.044 12054-12061/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.720ms
10-30 09:46:06.138 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 14.542ms
10-30 09:46:06.284 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 15.762ms
10-30 09:46:06.464 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 194534(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 13(968KB) LOS objects, 7% free, 48MB/52MB, paused 3.728ms total 127.593ms
10-30 09:46:06.476 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 11.657ms
10-30 09:46:06.550 12054-12061/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 13.106ms
10-30 09:46:06.664 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 13.684ms
10-30 09:46:06.821 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 14.076ms
10-30 09:46:07.000 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 16.330ms
10-30 09:46:07.016 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 202163(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 11(836KB) LOS objects, 7% free, 51MB/55MB, paused 19.939ms total 136.394ms
10-30 09:46:07.028 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 12.080ms
10-30 09:46:07.227 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 15.434ms
10-30 09:46:07.395 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 17.207ms
10-30 09:46:07.525 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 16.650ms
10-30 09:46:07.713 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 214425(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 12(948KB) LOS objects, 6% free, 53MB/57MB, paused 4.599ms total 122.695ms
10-30 09:46:07.725 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 12.268ms
10-30 09:46:07.928 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 16.880ms
10-30 09:46:08.080 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 20.240ms
10-30 09:46:08.094 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 160556(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 5(400KB) LOS objects, 3% free, 55MB/57MB, paused 24.451ms total 71.926ms
10-30 09:46:08.113 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 18.642ms
10-30 09:46:08.305 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 212686(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 11(880KB) LOS objects, 6% free, 55MB/59MB, paused 5.110ms total 134.449ms
10-30 09:46:08.319 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 14.065ms
10-30 09:46:08.535 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 15.462ms
10-30 09:46:08.712 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 17.943ms
10-30 09:46:08.907 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 19.325ms
10-30 09:46:08.930 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 219521(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 12(1004KB) LOS objects, 6% free, 58MB/62MB, paused 24.278ms total 157.949ms
10-30 09:46:08.948 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 17.521ms
10-30 09:46:09.067 12054-12061/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 12.066ms
10-30 09:46:09.170 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 18.647ms
10-30 09:46:09.361 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 19.054ms
10-30 09:46:09.583 12054-12061/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 25.753ms
10-30 09:46:09.619 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 18.583ms
10-30 09:46:09.634 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 228847(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 11(924KB) LOS objects, 6% free, 61MB/65MB, paused 22.781ms total 182.292ms
10-30 09:46:09.645 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 11.615ms
10-30 09:46:09.922 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 209342(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 6(528KB) LOS objects, 4% free, 62MB/65MB, paused 5.230ms total 98.012ms
10-30 09:46:09.943 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 21.805ms
10-30 09:46:10.175 12054-12061/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 114.591ms
10-30 09:46:10.206 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 157725(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 10(876KB) LOS objects, 6% free, 62MB/66MB, paused 4.308ms total 153.014ms
10-30 09:46:10.223 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 17.394ms
10-30 09:46:10.460 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 18.833ms
10-30 09:46:10.579 12054-12061/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 16.845ms
10-30 09:46:10.739 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 278135(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 11(968KB) LOS objects, 5% free, 64MB/68MB, paused 4.272ms total 179.332ms
10-30 09:46:10.752 12054-12065/br.com.vegait.android.hotelexperience W/art: Suspending all threads took: 12.981ms
```

And keep like this until crash. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

it´s me again.

Just to leave a feedback about my issue. I found the problem.

The object I was sending on request was different from the one mapped to be send.
Idk why it stuck de interceptor, but when I just change the object it worked like a charm. I will leave this here for someone else that might have the same problem.

Thank you any way.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to add crash log. But anyway log that you provide means that you're using memory, then it's being freed by the GC But seems like you do to much work and GC can't provide tp you enought memory and your app shot down with OutOfMemory exception. So first of all in this case you have to use Singleton pattern to avoid creation all of this Objects like (HttpClient, Gson, Interceptor ect..)So let's pretend this class entitled HttpClient. Then you need something like NetManager that will be a singleton..

```
public class NetManager {

    private static NetManager instance;
    private HttpClient httpClient;

    private NetManager() {
        httpClient = new HttpClient();
    }

    public static NetManager() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new NetManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public HttpClient getHttpClient() {
        return httpClient;
    }
}
```

And user your httpClient through this manager.

But in general it's a very very VERY bad to make network requests in a loop.